# React connect 2 buttons

Tags: forms, reactjs, button, redux, components

Hello i have a crazy problem:

Here is visualization:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/VDfxgDp]

The problem is I have structure like this:

**1) array Steps:**

|- stepOne

|- stepTwo

|- stepThree

|- stepFour

**2) Component Multistep:**

{here is logic of setting steps}

In the end of this component is

```
        <div>
          <button className={this.state.showNextBtn}
                  onClick={this.next}>Next</button>
        </div>
```

**onClick** is very important action to change step to next.

```
      next() {
        this.setNavState(this.state.compState + 1)
      }
```

next I have to render

```
const StepOneFormValidation = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="name"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Username"
        autoFocus
        require/>

      <Field name="email"
       type="email"
        component={renderField}
         label="Email"
        require/>

      <div>
        <button className ="hero_button margin_left" type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

So how can I connect this buttons?
I can't declare const in component form & not declare component in const

All Code:
https://pastebin.com/G47ZSfjM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways I see here:

**1:** Use react-router-redux;
Your routes could be like this `/form/step1`
and after form-submitting make `dispatch(push('/form/step2'))`, do not forget to create and apply `routerMiddleWare` with `history`.

**2:** 
Use global state for "stepper" or pass it's state as props; Imagine your global state:

```
{currentStep: 1, validate: {form1: true, form2: false, ...}}
```

You need control your "stepper" state globaly, using redux, or get it done by passing props from `<Stepper currentStep={this.props.currentStep}/>` component.

It would be much easier to control and understand everything in your app if decompose it to components like this:

```
render(){
    return (
       <div>
           <Stepper currentStep={this.props.currentStep}/>
           <Forms currentStep={this.props.currentStep} onSubmit={handleSumbitAndStepSwitching}/>
       </div>
    )
};
```

And in `<Forms />` you can make Switch-Case for control actual form rendered.

Comment: What solution should I try?

If I choose one, I will have next question, for example:

1.How can I make "Stepper" Global by using redux?

Comment: https://redux.js.org I've answered your question, but I can't write your code instead of you. You need to get experienced with redux firstly.

Comment: Yes, this problem is too complicated for my actually state of knowledge.